# Adjective meaning "disposable" that sounds more eco-friendly

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, adjectives

I'm marketing a product I invented for travelers. It's made of recyclable card stock. Travelers will use it for a week or less, and then either recycle it or throw it out.

"Disposable" is a good description, but doesn't sound eco-friendly.

"Recyclable" is too easily misinterpreted as meaning reusable.

I'd like to be able to use the word or phrase in my short product description: "The disposable [product] for hotel guests" or "The recyclable [product] for hotel guests".

Comment: Biodegradable, perhaps? https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/biodegradable

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of whether your product can actually be broken down by living organisms, you could use **biodegradable**, a marketing term which carries a strong connotation of having minimal environmental impact:

*The biodegradable [product] for hotel guests!*

Also, I don't think recyclable is easily confused with reusable. If your product is not designed to be thrown away, but rather to be reprocessed so other things can be made from it, you absolutely *should* use the word recyclable. If you wanted to specify that the product should only be used in the short-term (and it isn't obvious from the product itself), you could potentially say **single-use**:

*The single-use recyclable [product] for hotel guests!*